# Inserting and Searching for records by Insert Time in Apache Jena

Tags: jena

I need to periodically process data that is continuously being stored in a Jena data store. Is there any way to store an insert time for an RDF record when inserting the data?

Answer (score 0):

One of the interesting, and useful, features of RDF is that data and metadata are all stored at the same level - essentially in one graph (though see below for a caveat on this). So rather than having a separate place - such as the metadata attached to a database table - to record things like update time, in RDF you put that information, as triples, alongside the data itself.

So suppose I'm adding `example:Book` resources to my triple store. I could simply add a `dcTerms:modified` property to the resource itself, to encode the date of change:

```
example:eloquent_ruby
    a example:Book ;
    dcTerms:title "Eloquent Ruby"@en ;
    dcTerms:modified "2012-12-07T08:00:00"^^xsd:dateTime.
```

One potential gotcha is that, in doing so, I would have to be confident all the applications using that store understand that the `modified` triple denotes the time of update of the resource, not the last update of the book itself. This pattern probably works better if the resource type more obviously denotes a description of a thing rather than the thing itself - for example if the subject resource was a `example:PatientRecord` instead of `example:Book`.

I can mitigate the risk that update time is ambiguous by explicitly recording the *event* of updating the subject resource:

```
example:eloquent_ruby
    a example:Book ;
    dcTerms:title "Eloquent Ruby"@en ;
    dcTerms:identifier "0-321-58410-4".

<urn:uuid:6ba3f8ea-4048-11e2-82bc-ab86fea9a379> 
    a example:UpdateEvent ;
    example:about example:eloquent_ruby ;
    dcTerms:modified "2012-12-07T08:00:00"^^xsd:dateTime ;
    example:changed dcTerms:identifier , dcTerms:title.
```

Note: you don't have to use a UUID as the subject of the change record - any another synthesised ID or even a bNode would do. Personally I use bNodes less these days, simply because it's easier to work with named resources in the UI.

If, in your application, you don't want to put the content data and the provenance metadata in the same RDF graph, you could put the update records in a different named graph. This means that you have to remember to use the graph names in any SPARQL queries that you use (unless you rely on Jena TDB's [union default graph](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/assembler.html#union-default-graph) capability), but it does allow you to separately manage the content data and metadata, and to hide it from some users if necessary.

Comment: Is there a way to make the data store set the time, as opposed to my application?